# Setting background image - Android

Tags: android, xml

Ok, so i want to set a background image behind my 6 buttons, the header and the footer, i dont want anything to happen when someone clicks on it or anything like that.
Lets say the background png image is "@drawable/background".

Here is a picture of what the screen looks like at the moment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/66MoI.png

And here is my current relevant code:

dashboard_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/home_root"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- Include Action Bar -->
    <include layout="@layout/actionbar_layout"/>

    <!--  Include Fragmented dashboard -->  
    <include layout="@layout/fragment_layout"/> 

    <!--  Include Footer -->
    <include layout="@layout/footer_layout"/>
```

MenuActivity.java

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard_layout);

    /**
     * Creating all buttons instances
     * */
    Button btn_chat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_chat);

    Button btn_forums = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_forums);

    Button btn_donate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_donate);

    Button btn_reports = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reports);

    Button btn_commands = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_commands);

    Button btn_photos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_photos);

    /**
     * Handling all button click events
     * */
    btn_chat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChatActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    btn_forums.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ForumsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    btn_donate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DonateActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    btn_reports.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReportsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    btn_commands.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CommandsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    btn_photos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PhotosActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Thanks a mile in advance guys :)

Comment: set background for your `fragment_layout`